# Sitemap provider error

Tags: asp.net, sitemapprovider, web.config-transform

**Hi,
        I am not able to detect this error. I checked in the web.config file and there is no sitemap tag. Where should I be looking for this. Can someone point me in the right direction**

```
The SiteMapProvider 'SamplesSiteMap' cannot be found. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The SiteMapProvider 'SamplesSiteMap' cannot be found.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[HttpException (0x80004005): The SiteMapProvider 'SamplesSiteMap' cannot be found.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.get_Provider() +1213908
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetView(String viewName) +17
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String viewName) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.ConnectToDataSourceView() +253
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Answer (score 1):

sample

```
<system.web>
    <!-- SiteMap ConfigurationSettings -->
    <siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="MenuSiteMap">
      <providers>
        <add name="MenuSiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Menu.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

</system.web>
```

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.                                                          What does this error mean? Can you help?